# Any documentation link on perl program exit code without `exit()` statement

Tags: perl

My boss believes that perl program without explicit `exit(0)` at the end may return some other value, e. g. that one returned by the last function call in the program, or may be last system call. Perhaps he confuses it with bash.
So he requires his programmers to put explicit `exit(0)` statement at the end of each perl script.
Simple code examples or references to existing programs cannot convince him.
Unfortunately I have no idea how to find the relevant topic in the documentation quickly: all keywords are too common.
May be someone can point out exact place in the perl documentation what is the perl program exit code when the program just reaches its end, without any `die` or `exit`. (Yes, in fact I know what it is, but I need an official confirmation).

Comment: Probably some C infused trauma where `int main()` dictates a `return 0` to be correct.

Comment: `END` blocks can manipulate the exit code as they please, for one.  But then, of course, they may well have a good reason to do that -- but it is a case where just dropping off may not return 0

Comment: @toolic well, he is the boss, so he will not satisfy my request

Comment: `exit()` isn't necessary to end a perl script. Its more useful for letting the user know if the script closed without errors, `exit(0)` at the end of the script, or if the script came upon an error, `exit(1)` where you would CATCH a known error.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover  could you please also point out the place in the documentation or may be in some reputable book which covers you point?

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover  in fact I didn't fully understand your position: do you think that explicit exit(0) at the end of each script (when no errors were catched) is useful or not?

Comment: "_`END` blocks can manipulate the exit code as they please_" ... as well as `DESTROY` can

Comment: @vvch its not explicit, its implicit like in pilcrow's answer

Comment: The ability of `END` and `DESTROY` to set `$?` would deny the explicit `exit` -- the actual exit code will be whatever is set in `END`/`DESTROY`.  This would be an argument _against_ your boss's request to have explicit `exit` (since it wouldn't do as expected in some cases).

Comment: @tadman That hasn't been required in C for 25 years.

Comment: Sometimes in these situations, you just got to take one for the team and put the `exit(0)` in there even if you don't need it. Sometimes I just say "what do you want me to ignore this week while I fix this?"

Comment: @Shawn It's trauma , perhaps evolved into a superstition, not a requirement, just as here `exit(0)` is merely ceremonial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*perlrun* covers this](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#DESCRIPTION)

> If the program is syntactically correct, it is executed. If the program runs off the end without hitting an exit() or die() operator, an implicit `exit(0)` is provided to indicate successful completion.

Comment: ... unless there is an `END` block that changes `$?`, in which case that is the exit.  See [`$?` in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$?) and [`END` block in perlmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END).  Same with `DESTROY` which can change exit code

Comment: Ah yes, but `END` blocks and `DESTROY` code can override the exit code of an _explicit_ call to `exit(0)`, too, so that circumstance is not unique.

Comment: Yes indeed (and I noted that in a comment above) -- and in my view that's an argument against requiring an explicit `exit`, as it may not do what it appears to do.